# How can I get Hotmail contacts of users using the Live Connect API?

Tags: php, json, api, rest, hotmail

I found some Live API code for reading contacts but I don't know what are the parameters to send as well as the body data to get all contacts (me/contacts). The code I found is in this question [hotmail get contacts with curl using api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215563/hotmail-get-contacts-with-curl-using-api)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CloudSponge PHP library:
https://github.com/cloudsponge/cloudsponge-lib-php/

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.